# Moment generating function to distribution function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I was trying to show that the sum of i.i.d. normals is normal. Since I had no idea how to do it I started looking online and found out about **moment generating functions (MGF)**. Most proofs about that sum concluded the argument saying that **because the MGF of the sum equals the MGF of a normal, then the sum must be a normal ([example: look at last phrase of the document](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/6normgf.pdf))**.

**Question:** Why is it true? If two random variables have the same MGF, then they must have the same distribution? Is there a one-to-one correspondence between distributions and MGFs? Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes, same mgf implies same distribution.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where I could find the proof for this?

Comment: Most serious books do it. The one I have (oldie) is Feller, second volume.

Comment: To use characteristic functions rather than MGF is safer (no problem of convergence of integrals). For the fact that the MGF (when it exists in a neighborhood of zero) or the CF (always) indeed *characterize* the distribution, see the statements and references at the obvious places: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and instructive to prove the theorem directly, because the path through characteristic functions (or moment generating functions) is actually a very long one that requires far more than one might think, including complex analysis and dominated convergence theorem from measure theory.
$\def\pp{\mathbb{P}}$

**Notation**

Given random variable $X$, let "$f_X$" denote the density function for $X$.

**Convolution**

Given continuous real-valued independent random variables $X,Y$, and $Z = X+Y$:

For any $v \in \mathbb{R}$:

$\pp( Z \le v ) = \pp( Y \le v-X ) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{v-x} f_X(x) f_Y(y)\ dy\ dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{v} f_X(x) f_Y(y-x)\ dy\ dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^{v} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(y-x)\ dx\ dy$ [The swap is valid since the integrand is non-negative].

Thus $f_{Z}(v) = \frac{d}{dv} \pp( Z \le v ) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x) f_Y(v-x)\ dx$ [by FTC].

**Sum of normal random variables**

Given independent random variables $X \sim N(a,s^2)$ and $Y \sim N(b,t^2)$, and $Z = X+Y$:

Let $W = Z - (a+b) = (X-a) + (Y-b)$.

For any $v \in \mathbb{R}$:

$f_W(v) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πs^2}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2s^2}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πt^2}} \exp(-\frac{(v-x)^2}{2t^2})\ dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πs^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πt^2}} \exp(-\frac{ x^2 t^2 + (v-x)^2 s^2 }{ 2 s^2 t^2 })\ dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πs^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πt^2}} \exp(-\frac{ (s^2+t^2) x^2 - 2vx s^2 + v^2 s^2 }{ 2 s^2 t^2 })\ dx$

$= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πs^2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πt^2}} \exp(-\frac{ ( (s^2+t^2) x - v s^2 )^2 + v^2 s^2 t^2 }{ 2 s^2 t^2 (s^2+t^2) })\ dx$. [by completing the square]

$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π(s^2+t^2)}} \exp(-\frac{ v^2 }{ 2 (s^2+t^2) } ) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2πc}} \exp(-\frac{ ( x - v \frac{s^2}{s^2+t^2} )^2 }{ 2 c })\ dx$ where $c = \frac{s^2t^2}{s^2+t^2}$

$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2π(s^2+t^2)}} \exp(-\frac{ v^2 }{ 2 (s^2+t^2) } )$ [the above known integral motivates the previous steps].

Therefore $W \sim N(0,s^2+t^2)$ and hence $Z \sim N(a+b,s^2+t^2)$.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, I still haven't accepted it as a the answer because I haven't had the time to read it and understand it properly, I'll do that asap. Thanks again! :D

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: Sure. Feel free to ask if any part is not clear! This technique is the standard one to compute the density function of a sum of random variables, and you can try it on other usual ones like uniform or binomial or exponential.